# set up a data trigger on physical address

Tags: embedded, debugging, triggers, mips

Do you know any device out there can set up a data trigger on a physical address in MIPS ? I am using FS2 but It can only set up a trigger on virtual address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be a logic analyzer, especially one that understands the MIPS.  ([Here are some potential candidates.](http://www.home.agilent.com/agilent/product.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng&ckey=1000001966:epsg:pgr&nid=-536902443.0.00&id=1000001966:epsg:pgr))  These are pricey even to rent.  It [appears](http://www.fs2.com/pdfs/Using_PDtrace_with_MIPS_STK.pdf) there is no way to do what you want with FS2.

It would be probably be faster to calculate the physical address which relates to the virtual address, at least in the most likely process contexts.  Then simply set that as the trigger address.

Answer (score 0):

It is the on-chip debug hardware that uses virtual addresses, so the answer is probably 'no' unless you probe the actual address bus, which may not be physically possible in most cases